# Convert List object in a pandas dataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

One of my pandas dataframe column is a list object of m columns, each row looks like this
`'List(0.42, 0.24, 0.78,...)'` with a list of n elements wrapped by quote marks. Dtype for this column is Object.

I need to convert this column into a m X n np array. So far I tried applying np.fromstring(col content) but it's mostly returning 'ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size'. It did work for the first row though.

How to appropriately convert this List object column to an array?

Comment: How did you store you list string at the first place? I think it would be easier if you store your column values as actual lists instead of a string of your lists to begin with.

Comment: from downloaded sources

Comment: That's a string, not an actual `list`, or even a string that evals to `list`.  It's missing the `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need trim your string , then `split`

```
np.array(s.str.strip('List').str.strip('(|)').str.split(', ').tolist())
Out[11]: 
array([['0.42', '0,24', '0.78,...'],
       ['0.42', '0,24', '0.78,...']], dtype='<U8')
```

Updated

```
s.str.strip('List').str.strip('(|)').str.split(',',expand=True).apply(lambda x : x.str.strip()).values
Out[18]: 
array([['0.42', '0', '24', '0.78', '...'],
       ['0.42', '0', '24', '0.78', '...']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Note `0,24` in the list. I think one need more careful trimming. And this is a pandas data frame column from what I understand and not an array of strings.

Comment: @Fast response. But OP edited that to `0.24` :D . This solution will still work of course.

Comment: thanks to your answer @BEN_YO (1) I got it working with strip() and split instead of str.split, as it would return 'str' object has no attribute 'str' error (2) updated the 0,24 typo, it's just 0.24 (3) somehow the result dimension can be different from np.fromstring() could there be something wrong with np.fromstring?

Comment: @santoku I think the numpy from string should be return the correct result ~

Comment: @BEN_YO then could there be anything wrong with the str split method, because it looks correct too, and it works on every row. fromstring doesn't work on most of the rows for some unknown reason

Comment: @santoku then you may check your real data and see the different ~

Comment: @BEN_YO checked and found that fromstring likely doesn't work on this special format with the word 'list' in front.